# Installing GLFW on OSX

Tags: xcode, macos, installation, glfw

I've been all over the internet and I simply cannot find a way to install GLFW for OSX and use it with Xcode. A lot of articles use cmake for this, which I tried to install but I still can't access it from the terminal.

I just need a simple step-by-step guide for installing it because I'm going to lose my mind.

Thanks

Comment: Do you mean you can't install cmake or you don't know how to use cmake?

Comment: cmake has a bug where it can not install the command line tools.

Answer (score 15):

I use [homebrew](http://brew.sh/) to install GLFW. Once brew has been configured, use the commands

`brew tap homebrew/versions`

`brew install --build-bottle --static glfw2`

Answer (score 1):

If you are still running into trouble with this and want to use homebrew, change the install command to reflect the newer GLFW version (3 as of this writing)

```
brew tap homebrew/versions

brew install --build-bottle --static glfw3
```

Comment: I got "Warning: glfw: --static was deprecated; using --without-shared-library instead!" but the installation worked. Thanks.