# Set up OpenGL super bible sixth edition samples on Mavericks

Tags: c++, xcode, opengl, xcode5

I have difficulties when I am trying to set up examples from OpenGL Super bible sixth edition and execute them in Mac OS 10.9 and xcode 5. please help

Here is the step I did

1. install glfw2 using brew  according to [another stack question
   here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19410945/installing-glfw-on-osx)
2. download sample codes from [here](https://github.com/prabindh/sb6code)
3. cmake and make source code according to HOWTOBUILD file given.
4. create a "Command Line Tool" project in XCode
5. Specify "Header Search Paths" and "Library Search Path" in project "Build Settings" for
   libsb6.a and libglfw.a respectively.

Here is the code for main.cpp:

```
#include <sb6.h>
class my_application : public sb6::application
{
    public:
    void render(double currentTime)
    {
        static const GLfloat red[] = {1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f};
        glClearBufferfv(GL_COLOR, 0, red);
    }
};
DECLARE_MAIN(my_application);
```

when I ran the project I get the following error message

[image]

Comment: This is a _linking_ error. As I dont have XCode in front of me right now i cant say for sure which framework is missing, but i think it is one of these: `AppKit`, `Foundation`, `Cocoa`, `Carbon`

Comment: @t.niese: thanks for your help. the problem was Foundation.framework is missing. the compilation is OK now. thanks very much

Comment: Can you explain how you included gl3w? When I compile it gives an error that gl3w-functions are not defined.